# How to find one value from an IQueryable in C# ASP.NET MVC 4 using Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

This is in C# ASP.NET MVC 4 using EF. I have a table `Users` which has `Portfolio` object defined as one of its properties and `Username` as another. The `User.Identity.Name` in Razor lets me pass the username along to my controller once the person is logged in. A `User` has a `Portfolio_Id` in the table from the `Portfolio` object. What I am trying to do is obtain the `Portfolio_Id` of a `User` when all I have to go buy is the `Username`. In the code below you see I have a `var protfolioId`. My problem is that it is getting set as an `IQueryable<int>` from my LINQ when I need it to just be and int. I may be wrong but does that mean it is a collection and not a single value? How can I get just the `Portfolio_Id` for the `User` whose `Username` matched what I passed into the action?

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="id")]string userName)
    {
        //find the user
        var user = _db.Users
                   .Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
                   .Select(u => new User
                   {
                       Id = u.Id,
                       UserName = u.UserName,
                       FirstName = u.FirstName,
                       LastName = u.LastName,
                       Email = u.Email,
                       Portfolio = u.Portfolio
                   });
        //find the users portfolio id
        var portfolioId = user.Select(u => u.Portfolio.Id);

        //find their portfolio
        var portfolio = _db.Portfolios.Find(portfolioId);
        if(portfolio == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }//end of if
        return View(portfolio);
    }//end of Index
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var portfolio = _db.Users
                   .Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
                   .Select(u =>u.Portfolio)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
if(portfolio == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }//end of if
        return View(portfolio);
```

Comment: @user2998266 If the answer helped you, mark that and +1 to help another people.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a particular value in a specific data type like say int, like in my case i wanted to return an int, convert the IQueryable to an array then convert using ArrayName[0]

Comment: this is late answer so it is good to add some sample code(MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE).